# Concerning the return keyword

Tags: javascript, constructor, return, prototype, new-operator

I have created my own `new` function which creates an object and returns it

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName
    this.lastName = lastName
}

Person.prototype.getName = function () {
    console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName)
}

function spawn(constructor) {
    var obj = {}
    Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, constructor.prototype);
    var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
    return constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj

}

var crockford = spawn(Person, "Douglas", "Crockford")
crockford.getName()
```

The problem is that when i set the return like this:

`return constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj` it works, but when i set the return like the following:

`return obj || constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))` it says undefined

what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `obj || constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))`, the value returned is obj since the first value in the || condition was truthy. If it was false then only it would have tried to evaluate the other part.

However, your `obj` is `not empty`.

Line `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, constructor.prototype);` executes in both the cases and obj's prototype is set to that of Person since `constructor` parameter in spawn function is nothing but `Person`.

In first case, due to `return constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj` you call `Person` function with the parameters `Douglas` and `Crockford` but in second case you don't even call the constructor function.

Hence, firstName and lastName properties cannot be attached to the `this` object.

Because of lack of firstName and lastName values, you see undefined undefined, whereas in first case due to call to constructor function, you saw Douglas Crockford.

To be clear `return constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj` will return second part of || since `constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))` will return undefined. The properties firstName and lastName will be attached to the `obj` object itself due to `apply()`.

Comment: So how `constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))`  is false?

Comment: @AhMedRaXa The call `constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))` makes a call to the Person function with Douglas and Crockford as arguments. Due to this when you call getName(), the function has this.firstName and this.lastName.

Comment: I meant how evaluation of  `constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))` is false so that it is evaluating the right side of the `||`  ?

Comment: So is it returning both sides?

Comment: @AhMedRaXa You have two cases right? In first case an object is returned with firstName and lastName set, so that you could see the right output. In second case an object is returned that doesn't have firstName and lastName set. The reason it is not set in second case is due to | | condition. Hope it's clear now!

Comment: I am understanding what you are saying...
Just Explain me the parsing of this code:

`return constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj`

what javascript does when it reaches this line. tell me behind the scenes.

Comment: @AhMedRaXa `return constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj` will be evaluated with first part being falsy since Person doesn't return anything. The other part which is `obj` has firstName and lastName  attached to obj, the call will return obj.

Comment: @AhMedRaXa So yes, in `first case` second part of || and in `second case`, first part of || would be returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143716/discussion-between-ahmed-raxa-and-pankaj-shukla).

Comment: Is this statement same as above? 

`var app = constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))`


`return obj || app`

Comment: @AhMedRaXa Yes whether you say `obj || app` or `app || abj` both are equivalent since one is undefined(falsy) and the other is truthy.

Comment: @AhMedRaXa I would suggest that you do some debugging in the chrome developer tools. That would help you further!

Comment: So the left hand side is also executed(even bieng falsy) before returning obj?